# A week before my next job -- how do I spend time wisely ramping up?

Tags: communication, new-hires, knowledge-transfer

One of my concerns from my last job (internship) was my lack of relevant skill set which led to me not getting a full-time offer.

How do I politely send an email to my future mentors (whom I have already met and interacted with in-person) to understand what skills I need during my job?

Comment: Did you make it through the whole interview process without gleaning anything about what skills you will need that you may be lacking?

Comment: Here's the language you need:  "Hey guys, I'm desperate to start work already.  I want to get a jump on things.  What libraries/ IDEs/ systems/ whatever will I be using on day one for the blah-blah system?"   Simply state the question like that - "Tell me the XYZ I'll be working on on day one" -  don't give any "reasons" why you want to know that (it's obvious why you want to know - because you're keen).  Enjoy!

Comment: Actually I found an email exactly like this!  **"Desperate to get started, want a jump on things, what will we be using on day 1?"**  That's all you need to say!  Then work your ass off on that until then!  Enjoy

Answer (score 6):

I would not phrase it in such a manner.

Send an email and don't ask what skills you should have.

Instead, ask what the first few weeks will be like, what you will focus on, what your duties will be, and what skillsets/technologies will be involved.  Tell them that you want to take this week to "brush up" on those things, get in the right mindset and be able to "hit the ground running"

Comment: Well said - don't put it as a negative!